# Error upgrading to Mongo java driver 3.2.2

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

we have migrated to MongoDB 3.2.6. What could be the compatible mongo version jars for below dependencies,

1. mongo java driver version (org.mongodb)
2. spring data mongo version (org.springframework.data)
3. spring data commons version (spring-data-commons)

I have tried to upgrade these to 3.2.2 for java driver and 1.9.4.RELEASE for spring data and spring commons but facing maven compatible issues. Below 2 issues i'm unable to resolve as of now.

Kindly suggest what could be the problem.

Issue 1:

```
The type org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryByExampleExecutor cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Issue 2:

```
Error occured processing XML 'Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class 
 org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()'. See Error Log for more details
```

Tried `mvn clean dependency:tree` and it is successful. But `mvn clean compil`e is failing with Issue 1 error mentioned above.

**Answer:**
I'm able to resolve both the issues by upgrading to 1.12.1 for spring-data-commons. This will resolve above mentioned compile time issues.
Below are my current settings.
mongo-java-driver to 3.2.2, spring-data-mongodb to 1.9.4.RELEASE, spring-data-commons to 1.12.1. 
As per Spring data commons documentation [Spring Data Commons](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#dependencies.spring-framework) I also upgraded my Spring framework version to 4.2.8.RELEASE.

Facing below issue which I couldn't resolve. Any ideas will be appreciated.

**Issue1:**

```
06:37:33.943 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.c.t.c.AnnotationAttributesReadingVisitor - Failed to class-load type while reading annotation metadata. This is a non-fatal error, but certain annotation metadata may be unavailable.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Nullable
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139) ~[catalina.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.visitEnd(RecursiveAnnotationAttributesVisitor.java:47) ~[spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1802) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:976) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:695) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:64) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:121) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.filter.AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.match(AbstractTypeHierarchyTraversingFilter.java:105) [spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate$LenientAssignableTypeFilter.match(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:202) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:346) [spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:280) [spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.multipleStoresDetected(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:167) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.<init>(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:88) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:80) [spring-data-commons-1.12.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Tried adding dependency jsr305 from com.google.code.findbugs but still seeing same exceptions.

Comment: Seems you need upgrading to `spring-data-commons` `1.12.4.RELEASE`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I resolved both the issues by upgrading to 1.12.1 for spring-data-commons. All my compile time issues are resolved.